# Why is granting permissions to a user for a particular table in Postgres actually granting them to two users?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

Let's say I have two postgres users, "first" and "second".

I'm granting all permissions to "first" via `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb TO first;`

When I run `\dp` the "Access privileges" column is blank, even though "first" has access to all tables.

Then I'm granting privileges to "second" for a particular table:

`GRANT SELECT ON mytable TO second;`

The `mytable` permissions then look like this:

```
first=arwdDxt/first+
second=r/first
```

Then, if I `REVOKE` permissions from "second", it appears that "first" still gets permissions on this table, i.e., running `REVOKE ALL on mytable FROM second;` leaves permissions like this on each table for which "second" used to have permissions:

```
first=arwdDxt/first
```

What I would have expected to happen is that the Access privileges would be blank again, not have this "residual" access privilege from "first" still show up for that table.

Why is this "residual" access privilege still showing up?

Comment: Maybe the bug is that it doesnt show the permissions yhe first time. Have you tried to access the tables to prove it?

Comment: Yes I can access all tables with "first" user - and it appears that my privileges on `mytable` are the exact same as before. It's just very odd that the privilege shows up even though all I did was add and then revoke a privilege from "second" - I didn't make any changes to "first"'s privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original state of the table (which must have been owned by "first") is just represented by the empty string, meaning the default perms. But once that is disturbed, then you get the perms spelled out. When you remove the extra perms, they remain spelled out. They mean the same thing, they are just spelled differently.